# Entering sampling rate when displaying digital filter response in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am trying to use `fvtool` function in Matlab (2011a).

This is an interactive "tool" composed of many functions. My code goes like this:

```
%fs1=256; fs2=64; fs3=32; 
b1 = fir1(52,0.25,kaiser(53,7.85726));
b2 = fir1(40,0.5,kaiser(41,7.85726));
b3 = fir1(204,0.5,kaiser(205,10.0613));
fvtool(b1,1,b2,1,b3,1);
```

This produces:
[image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/sZunQTHJ/1_online.html]

Now I go to the "analysis" menue and choose "sampling frequency", and enter the sampling freq. for each filter. The result is:

[image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/sZunQTHJ/2_online.html]

Not very good, since the response of the second and third filters is repeating. The response of the first filter is fine, going from 0 to 256/2=128 Hz. I would like to have the response of the second and third filters to go up to 64/2=32 and 32/2=16. respectively.

So I tried to manually do it,

```
%Digital filter:
fs1=256; fs2=64; fs3=32; 
b1 = fir1(52,0.25,kaiser(53,7.85726));  b1(end+256)=0;
b2 = fir1(40,0.5,kaiser(41,7.85726));   b2(end+448)=0;
b3 = fir1(204,0.5,kaiser(205,10.0613)); b3(end+480)=0;

%Filters Response
n=1024;
w = logspace(-1,2,n);

digi_1 = freqz(b1,1,n,fs1); semilogx(w,20*log10(abs(digi_1)),'Color','k'); hold on
digi_2 = freqz(b2,1,n,fs2); semilogx(w,20*log10(abs(digi_2)),'Color','b'); hold on
digi_3 = freqz(b3,1,n,fs3); semilogx(w,20*log10(abs(digi_3)),'Color','r'); 
axis ([0.1 128 -140 10])
```

Here I used freqz and give it the filter numerator and denomenator, plus the number of points n, plus the sampling freq. fs. The problem is that Matlab does not seem to do any change with or without the sampling freq., i.e. if I left it nothing change.

So if someone wants to help, he/she would either help me with `fvtools` or with my manual code which is a step late than `fvtools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is actually a friend's solution, but I will post it here for the sake of knowledge sharing.

Basically the problem with my code is that I define the x-axis points myself (`w = logspace(-1,2,n);`), and this is somehow incompatible with the y-axis points returned from freqz. Rather than that, I should have simply used the x-axis points returned from freqz, since actually freqz returns both y and x aisx points.

So the only change below is in w being used from freqz rather than defined manually.

```
%Digital filter:
fs1=256; fs2=64; fs3=32;                                                   % Sampling frequencies.
b1 = fir1(52,0.25,kaiser(53,7.85726));%32                                  % Defining filter 1 parameters
b2 = fir1(40,0.5,kaiser(41,7.85726)); %16                                  % Defining filter 2 parameters
b3 = fir1(204,0.5,kaiser(205,10.0613));%8                                  % Defining filter 3 parameters

n=1024

[h1,w1] = freqz(b1,1,n,fs1); fig1=semilogx(w1,20*log10(abs(h1)),'Color','k'); hold on
[h2,w2] = freqz(b2,1,n,fs2); fig2=semilogx(w2,20*log10(abs(h2)),'Color','b'); hold on
[h3 w3] = freqz(b3,1,n,fs3); fig3=semilogx(w3,20*log10(abs(h3)),'Color','r');
```

I don't remember why I tried to define w (the x-axis points) manually, but that's it.

Comment: To conform with Matlab documentation syntax, I should have written [h1 f1] instead of [h1 w1]. Not a big deal, but may eliminate confusion when referring to the documentation. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks almost like the `fir1` does not like your choice for `Wn` for the second two filters.  Try reducing the `Wn`.

**EDIT**
I hope this will be more clear, sorry for the confusion, I originally thought the `Wn` was scaled differently, sorry.

You're right `n`, specifies the length of the filter, and it's order.  The higher the filter order can increase the chances for numerical instability.  In The Mathworks documentation calls out:

```
b = fir1(n,Wn,window)
```

Which then

> returns row vector b containing the n+1 coefficients of an order n
>   lowpass FIR filter. This is a Hamming-window based, linear-phase
>   filter with normalized cutoff frequency Wn. The output filter
>   coefficients, b, are ordered in descending powers of z.
>
> Wn is a number between 0 and 1, where 1 corresponds to the Nyquist frequency.

So, you're first filter:

```
% sampling frequency 256 Hz
b1 = fir1(52,0.25,kaiser(53,7.85726));
```

Works just great!  Whereas the next two

```
% sampling frequency 64 Hz
b2 = fir1(40,0.5,kaiser(41,7.85726));
% sampling frequency 32 Hz
b3 = fir1(204,0.5,kaiser(205,10.0613));
```

Show a periodic response, which would indicate some sort of numerical problem to me.  Are there any warnings when you create these filters/windows?  Mathworks documentation shows the following for the specification of the Kaiser window.

[image: Kaiser Specification]

Where alpha is the dB of attenuation in the stop band.  Is this value too high perhaps?  Try relaxing this value and see if the filter behaves as you would expect.

Comment: n is just a resolution, number of points. It has nothing to do with the actual filtering things. I changes it up and down and no difference. Note that w (and hence n) should be the same for all 3 filters since I am plotting all of them on the same graph

Comment: Changing the values of the Kaiser window did not remove the periodicity of the other two filters.

Note that one of them goes to 128 Hz (since I am displaying till fs/2) which is fine. The others keep repeating.

This suggest that it may not be a problem of the filter itself, rather, I think, it is in the response function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
hd1 = dfilt.dffir(b1);
hd2 = dfilt.dffir(b2);
hd3 = dfilt.dffir(b3);

h = [hd1 hd2 hd3];
freqz(h);
```

**EDIT 1**
Actually, this might give you the same problem in the original statement... give me a minute... *update* confirmed; it does.

**EDIT 2**
So try this instead:

build your filters *with* the fs into them a la:

```
fs1 = 256;
fpass = .4*fs;
fstop = .5*fs;
band_limits = [fpass fstop];
band_type = [1 0]; % 0 = stop, 1 = pass
ripple_dB = .1; % ripple mag
stop_db = -60; % stopband attenuation
dstop = 10^(stop_db/20);
dpass = abs(1-10^(ripple_db/20/2));
dev = [dpass dstop]; % ripple spec
c1 = kaiserord(band_limits,band_type,dev,fs1,'cell'); % kaiserwindow builder 
b1 = fir1(c{:}); % filter spec'd to window
```

*etcetera*, then... do the first block of code (`h = [hd1 hd2 hd3]`) and when you call freqz, you can just normalize your sampling freq, and everything *should* be displaying as you expect.

This is probably a lengthy solution. There's probably a way in `fvtool` or `freqz` that allows you to change the parameters of each filter to "shape" it to the sampling window.

**EDIT 3** 
In all actuality, the default "normalized frequency" view is sufficient.

If fs1 = 256 Hz, then per sample, 2π = 256 samples. π is 128 samples. You can see this by going to `fvtool -> View -> Analysis Parameters ... -> [x] Normalized Frequency` after you have entered an Fs for filter 1. You can see how cutoff is at 1/4 2π, which you specified. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not working. I repeated the block for the other two filters. First issue is that I am implementing my FIR filters using specific transfer function, your method do it using a windowing technique, so I got a different response.

Comment: You're definitely not seeing a response of the filter, I'm positive you're seeing aliasing due to differing sampling frequencies. If you run `fvtool` individually on your filters (`fvtool(b1,1)` _etc_) and enter the single freqs for each, you'll see what I mean. Your filters are designed well and display as expected individually, but `fvtool` will plot them all on the same graph as a function of your highest sample rate (256 Hz) which will alias the rest. I'm still working on how to fix that...

Comment: To be honest, I'm unsure how to fix the issue. However, I will comment that that only view you really need to see the response of your filter at any sampling rate is the normalized frequency response `fvtool` defaults to. The normalized frequency response, [0 1] pi rads/sample is equivilent to [0 fs/2] which is what you see as filter 1's response in your second figure. In your normalized frequency response, all your filters perform as expected at their sampling frequencies. I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Yes you are right about the aliasing issue. That helps, although I still have to rethink and try to get a solution. Thank you.

Comment: If you do discover a solution please share! The only way I've ever been able to defeat aliasing is subplotting and redefining the x axis for differing sampling rates--which is not always ideal!